# Is it possible to activate the animated busy/progress indicator outside of a WorkUnit?

Tags: eyeshot

I would like to activate the spinning progress indicator and specify a message on the Eyeshot control to provide feedback to the user when other long running processes are occurring that are related to the items in the view.  This work is happening outside of any Eyeshot WorkUnit.  Is it possible to control the indicator separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an article in the help centre that explains [Using a Synchronous ProgressBar](https://devdept.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007914779-Synchronous-ProgressBar)

Answer (score 1):

I guess not if the process is not on a separate thread. This is also the reason why you should implement this in your `WorkUnit` derived class.

Comment: I stumbled across this in the help centre while looking for something else.  Seems to be what I was asking for:  https://devdept.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007914779-Synchronous-ProgressBar

Comment: Yes, but blocking the UI is not a good practice. If you derive a class from the WorkUnit, during the process the end user can continue to Zoom/Pan/Rotate the model instead of waiting on a frozen scene.